# MKDIR() Permission Denied Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, logging, mkdir

i need a logs from codeigniter 3.
But i got this error message,

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mkdir(): Permission denied
>
> Filename: core/Log.php
>
> Line Number: 122
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/admin/mysite/index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

How can i solve this?

Comment: What is the Logging Directory Path you set in config.php file? 

You can specify the path $config['log_path'] = ''; If you set nothing on this variable, then log will write "application/logs/" 

Check whether you have set proper folder permission for writing logs.

Comment: If in logs folder make sure you have set the correct folder permissions I think 0700 is fine

Comment: i did it, but no changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter has some error logging functions built in. You can log any errors to system log with function [log_message](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html#log_message)

Also you can set log level in your application/config/config.php
here is the sample settings:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       0                           = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|       1                           = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|       2                           = Debug Messages
|       3                           = Informational Messages
|       4                           = All Messages|
*/
```

- Make your */application/logs* folder writable
- In */application/config/config.php* set 
  `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`
   or use a higher number, depending on how much detail you want in your logs
- Use `log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');`

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This mean that your app cannot create application/logs folder, because it doesn't have permission.

Go to applications folder;
Create "logs" folder (without quotes);
Give permission to folder: chmod 0755 logs.

That's it.